# JS: Почему this.images[i] является undefined?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, конструктор, context

Необходимо сделать ООП слайдер. HTML-конструкция:

```
<div class="gallery gallery-1">
            <div class="photos">
                <img src="img/Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="showed" alt="">
                <img src="img/Desert.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Jellyfish.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Koala.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Lighthouse.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Penguins.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/Tulips.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input type="button" value="Назад" class="prev">
                <input type="button" value="Вперёд" class="next">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Картинки в позиции Absolute. У первой картинки стоит класс 'showed', который показывает картинку. При нажатии на кнопку назад или вперёд, этот класс у текущий картинки удаляется, счётчик увеличивается (или уменьшается) на единицу и добавляет класс 'showed' следующей картинке.
CSS 'showed':

```
.gallery .photos img.showed{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Функции-конструктору, в качестве параметра, передаётся объект:

```
var slider = new Slider({
      images: '.gallery-1 .photos img',
      btnPrev: '.gallery-1 .buttons .prev',
      btnNext: '.gallery-1 .buttons .next',
      auto: true //флаг автопрокрутки изображений
  });
}
```

Описание функции-конструктора:

```
function Slider(obj) {
    var i = 0;    
    this.images = document.querySelectorAll(obj.images);
    this.btnPrev = document.querySelector(obj.btnPrev);
    this.btnNext = document.querySelector(obj.btnNext);
    this.auto = obj.auto;

    this.btnNext.onclick = function(){

        this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
        i++;
        if(i >= this.images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        this.images[i].classList.add('showed'); 
    }
    this.btnPrev.onclick = function(){
        this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
        i--;
        if (i < 0) {
            i = this.images.length-1;
        }
        this.images[i].classList.add('showed');
    }


    if(this.auto) {
        setInterval(function(){

        this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
        i++;
        if(i >= images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        this.images[i].classList.add('showed'); 
    }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Этот код не работает. Однако, если я сделаю вот так:

```
var img = this.images;
```

Подставив после этого переменную img вместо this.images, код работает. 
А так же он работает, если сразу делать:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(obj.images);
```

Как я понимаю, this.images виден только на верхнем уровне функции. И из любой другой вложенной функции (например обработчика) виден не будет? То есть контекст потеряется?

Только вхожу в ООП. Прошу понять и простить. Если есть материалы на тему this, которые именно Вам помогли его полностью понять - поделитесь!

Comment: В отличие от переменных,ключевое слово this не имеет области видимости, и вложенные функции не наследуют значение this от
 вызывающей функции. Если вложенная функция вызывается как метод, значением this является объект, относительно которого был сделан вызов. Если вложенная функция вызывается как функция,то значением this будет либо глобальный объект (в нестрогом режиме),
либо undefined (в строгом).